# Place canvas photo in right directory using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, file-upload

I have a form that allows someone to upload multiple files, text and a canvas (sketch) up to a server. When the form gets submitted the script creates a folder based on the date (YmdHis) so the folders are called similiar like this: 20150109135640. Everything works except for the canvas, for some reason it works when I tell the script exactly where to put it, for instance:

`$fopen = fopen( 'uploads/testmap/test.png', 'wb' );`

This works great but what I need is something like this, where `$mapname = date('YmdHis');` is the place where the file needs to be placed:

`$fopen = fopen( 'uploads/'.$mapname.'/test.png', 'wb' );`

This doesn't work and i don't know why, when I do `echo $mapname;` at the bottom of the script it echoes the correct folder, I checked it and they match with the folder that is created on the server.

This script is before the form but after the PHP that uploads the other files and creates the folder

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveIt() {
        var myDrawing = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
        var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("images/png");
        var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST",'saveimage.php',true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            }
            ajax.send(postData);
    }
    </script>
```

This is my saveimage.php with the echo still in it:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $rawImage=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $removeHeaders=substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
    $decode=base64_decode($removeHeaders);
    $fopen = fopen( 'uploads/'.$mapname.'/test.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fopen, $decode);
    fclose( $fopen );
}

echo $mapname;
?>
```

So it echoes the correct folder (that is created on form submittion) but for some reason it can't place the .png in the folder. This script is loaded AFTER the folder is created so I really don't get the problem.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

---

I fixed it, I made a stupid typo error that solved it I guess, after I changed this it suddenly worked.

var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("images/png"); 
To
var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("image/png");

Comment: Do you have write permissions on $mapname folder?

Comment: do you get an error?, if so: what would that error be?

Comment: check your error logs for errors. highly likely its a permissions thing.

Comment: And by "you", @WaldsonPatricio means whatever user the web server is running under.

Comment: The folder is created with 0777 permission, so permissions shouldn't be a problem :/

Comment: I fixed it, I'll add the answer to my problem so other know too! Thanks for the help :)